# How best to handle static text in frontend frameworks such as Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, web-frontend

I'm working on a Web Application which uses Vue.js as the frontend framework. Currently we are handling static text directly where it is used i.e. inputting it directly at source in components data.

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        data: function () {
            return {
              title: 'Business Title',
              modalBodyText: 'Some business text that devs don't care about'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However the Web App requires a lot of input from the business team on how things are phrased and how text is worded. Due to compliance some of the text in the application changes frequently and I am wondering whether there is a better way of handling static text in frontend frameworks such as Vue.js?

I feel we should be abstracting out the static text from the code and importing a file globally but I'm unsure if this is common practice or how best to do it. Any input on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ . Its purpose is for translations, but you can of course use it with a single language as well. It also helps you if you at some point want to translate your application, as you then dont need to extract all the strings from each component.

Comment: It is possible to import markdown files as sources for text files. Remark for Vue is a parser that could help with that: [remark repo](https://github.com/medfreeman/remark-vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing you can do is to create some `json` file (or multiple files ...depending how big and structured your app is) with all the texts and simple import it into your components

```js
import content from './content.json'
```

Webpack will make content of such file available as JS object so you can easily reference keys in your code (not directly from template tho)

Slightly more sophisticated way would by to use of I18n libraries like `vue-i18n` - still keeping your text in separate `json` files with some utilities on top for accessing it directly from templates - but with an option of changing text storage mechanisms later and using many open source tools available for managing and changing the content by non-developer users...